# Check if a word is a palindrome

Tags: python

First of all, I have checked if this question relates to any old posts, but these haven't helped me. If it does relate to any old posts, I am terribly sorry.

This relates to a practice python coding exercise that I have been working on.

As the code is incomplete, I am going to explain what the program does below:

The program asks the user for an input, any input. It then checks if the input is a palindrome, and prints different texts depending on the outcome (wether or not the user's input is a palindrome).

I am completely unsure on how to solve this. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Help on your part would also be very welcome, in the form of a minimum attempt to answer the question you post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so to get input, you either use [`raw_input()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input) if you're using Python 2 or [`input()`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#input) if you're using Python 3.

Once you get the word entered, you can reverse the string by using slicing:

```
>>> print 'hello'[::-1]
olleh
>>> print 'racecar'[::-1]
racecar
```

Then, *`if`* the reversed string equals the input given, say that it is a palindrome. *`else`*, say that it isn't a palindrome.

Answer (score 0):

another (less obvious) approach:

```
if s == ''.join(list(reversed(s))):
    print 's is a palindrome'
else:
    print 's is not a palindrome'
```

with slices (Haidro's asnwer) is better for sure

Comment: THe point really isn't to give the solution, but to help them attain it